# Can't view streaming program

Tags: youtube, moonlight, video-streaming

i am almost new in ubuntu (so I need detailed help) and I am not able to view sport streaming events on the web.

I have problem with

1. Eurosport (on Eurosportplayer)
2. Youtube

on the FAQs for Eurosport player is written that the player do not support Linux for Silverlight reasons, but I find a lot of guide to bypass this problems (I downloaded some plugins that I do not remember the names).

It seems it works with moonlight but it is not supported yet, so I need another way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For silverlight use

```
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:ehoover/compholio
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:mqchael/pipelight
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install pipelight
```

Flash for youtube

```
sudo apt-get install flashplugin-nonfree
```

it should work

Comment: For Flash, you may install this instead: `flashplugin-installer`

Comment: don't use ehoover,mqchael PPA's for pipelight.plz see http://fds-team.de/cms/pipelight-installation.html.

Comment: I do not know what that istructions are, but it works!